# kind like templates or something like it for openshift and kuberneties in one moment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I need to do configs for Openshift and Kubernetes in one repo. I use Templates in Openshift, but Kubernetes can't understand what a Template is. What can I use that will work in both OpenShift and vanilla Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, `Templates` is an OpenShift-specific resource. I would not recommend using it but instead use something like [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) to do templating for both OpenShift and also for Kubernetes.

Since Kubernetes 1.14, there is the `kubectl kustomize` command built in, so you do not even need to install another tool for it.

Here is a basic tutorial for Kustomize in the Kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/

Comment: It's not worth a separate answer, but another option would be Helm. Templates are nice because they are simple, but being simple (and OpenShift specific) is also their limitation. Helm is arguably the most flexible, with Kustomize being somewhat of a middle ground.